# Integration Testing Emails sent from an MVC3 .Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, integration-testing

What is a good way to produce reliable integration test results for a mail service in a development environment for a .NET MVC3 web application?  The email service is already isolated behind an interface and the unit tests are written for it, but I was curious if there are there any good, general tools or strategies that are available to make it easy other than spamming some email address and having some full-blown smtp server setup somewhere.

Things that should be easy to test should be:
 - given a correct setup, can an email be sent
 - given an incorrect setup, can we detect it and get that status back.

Comment: Curious, it sounds like your trying to send out mass emails through a web page.  If this is the case then you may want to read this post.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623872/sending-out-20-000-emails-with-asp-net

Comment: Doesn't integration test imply testing it against the smtp server you'll be using?  

There is little value in your tests if you fake up a smtp server locally or something and test against that.

Comment: the value in testing it against the fake smtp server is that I can test that the service is working correctly and the emails are being sent to the smtp server correctly.  I'm just making sure I can verify that everything I can possibly do is correct rather than "coding and praying"

Answer (score 7):

A good tip if you're using your `web.config` to store you SMTP server settings is that you can use the following configuration to dump all emails sent into a directory on your development environment.

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
      <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\email"/>
      <network host="localhost"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: I agree with this approach.  I've done something similar, implemented an EmailProviderFactory that lets you specify the default provider in the web.config.  In Production it is set to give back a provider that will send emails, in Dev it is set to give back a provider that writes the emails to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use special version of SMTP servers made for testing, look at:

[Testing Mail Functionality with Neptune](http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2009/06/24/Testing-E_2D00_Mail-Functionality.aspx)

[Antix Developer SMTP server](http://antix.co.uk/Projects/SMTPServerForDevelopers)